# Battery life in Lenovo y700 (15)

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I own a Lenovo y700 laptop. I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu, and the battery life is approximately 2.5 hours. Regularly I use the computer for web surfing, writing documents & reading. With that said, 2.5 hours seems to me like a very short amount of time. Plus I asked a friend who uses windows and runs much more heavy programs and the battery life is ~5 hours (which IMO is also somewhat short, but whatever, I can live with 5 hours battery life).

I still have warranty, so I sent the computer to Lenovo lab twice,  first time they replaced the battery, claiming it's worn out, which sounded kinda weird because I almost didn't use the computer since I bought it.

Replacing the battery didn't seem to have any impact. Since I'm using a fresh install I wasn't not convinced there isn't a hardware problem. I contacted them again, and this time the lab claimed that everything is ok. The technician specifically mocked me when I mentioned benchmarks, claiming that "benchmarks aren't the real world" and he also said that 2 hours for y700 is as expected. He also claimed that y700 bios "isn't fit to work with ubuntu".

What do you guys think? Could battery life be shortened because of a hardware problem that isn't related to the battery? Is it Ubuntu?

I would love to hear your input, 2 hours seems like a very short amount of time to web surfing, especially since this laptop is designed for Gamers, what, gamers have battery life of 20 minutes? Plus all the benchmarks are talking about ~5 hours. Although the benchmarks are performed on windows, they still give you a rough estimation I believe.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few likely things to check:

- Version of Ubuntu: Up-to-date? Desktop or server? LTS or quarterly?
- Screen brightness: If it's up, the battery will be down.
- CPU control: *[cpupower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854017/ubuntu-16-04-desktop-performance-setting-cpu-frequency-governor-to-performance/854049)* can be set for greater power economy. See [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cpupower.1.html).
- Install [powertop](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/powertop-will-maximize-your-linux-laptops-battery-life/): That's an Ingtel CPU management utility: **sudo apt-get install powertop**
- Cooling: If the cooling fan runs continuously, then battery life might benefit from a utility such as [*thermald*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues).
- See [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-improve-battery-life-in-Ubuntu-16-04-LTS) for more on this issue.